# Unable to Identify All Text Elements on Page with XPath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to identify all text elements on web page. Based on several threads I've read on stackoverflow I've come up with the following XPath:

```
//*[normalize-space(.)=.][not(self::script or self::style or self::meta)]//.
//*[normalize-space(.)=.][not(self::script or self::style or self::meta)]//text()
```

However, I noticed that while this identifies several hundred text elements on Amazon product page, it leaves out some important ones.

For example:

On [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J24C0TI) page I am not able to identify the 'features' section and order by time section:

> "Echo Show brings you everything you love about Alexa.."
>
> 'Want it tomorrow.."

On [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615797806) page I cannot identify the description section (immediately to the right of product image)

Both of these pages have text that are prominently displayed on the page so I do not see why it is not identifying them accordingly.

I'm aware that some of these text are under `ul/li` tags but I don't think this is the issue.

Finally, would it be possible to combine the said XPath with another attribute value so it only identifies text elements with given attribute value (i.e,  `//*[normalize-space(.)=.][not(self::script or self::style or self::meta)]//.` + `.//*[@id='XYZ']`)

Thanks

Comment: Probably because of this: `[normalize-space(.)=.]` Try removing that predicate. I think you'd also need to use `and` instead of `or` in the other predicate. Example (untested): `//*[not(self::script) and not(self::style) and not(self::meta)]//text()`

Comment: Also, it's unclear what you mean by "text elements". Do you want to select text nodes or select elements that contain text?

Comment: @DanielHaley If I remove `[normalize-space(.)=.]` it identifies hundreds of whitespace elements which I don't want. By text elements I mean any element that has some visible text on page.. Basically, the kind of text you might see if you viewed the page yourself. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try `//*[text()[not(normalize-space()='')]]` then. That should select any element that has a text() node as a direct child that isn't just whitespace.

Comment: try `//body//*[text()[not(normalize-space()='')]][not(self::script or self::style or self::meta or self::noscript)]`    or  try  `//body//*[not(normalize-space(text())='')][not(self::script or self::style or self::meta or self::noscript)]`

Comment: @DanielHaley Brilliant! Works perfectly. Thanks! Now I could just combine this with id (or other attribute) as follows: `//*[contains(@id, 'product')][text()[not(normalize-space()='')]]` - basically guaranteed to select any element with visible text with id containing 'product' (in other words it will not select other type of elements such as input, image etc even if it matches id) I would accept as answer if you wish to add it as one Thanks you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
//*[text()[not(normalize-space()='')]]
```

That will select any element that has a text() node as a direct child that isn’t just whitespace.